# Константные параметры шаблона и генерация кода

Tags: c++, visual-studio, шаблоны-с++

Добрый день.

Транслятор Visual Studio 2017.

Есть код:

```
template<class Tdata, bool flag> class example{

    Tdata data;

public:

    example(){}

    void run() {
        if (flag == true) delete[] data;
    }

};

example<char*,true> class_char;
example<int, false> class_int;
```

Когда я вызываю

```
class_char.run();
```

То все нормально.

Когда я вызываю

```
class_int.run();
```

Появляется ошибка трансляции:

> Ошибка    C2541   delete: нельзя удалять объекты, не являющиеся
>   указателями

Вопрос:

1. Почему строка:

   ```
       if (flag == true) delete[] data;
   ```

Вообще транслируется, если на этапе трансляции известно, что параметр шаблона flag равен false?

Спасибо.

Comment: А при чем здесь вообще шаблоны? Напишите просто `if  (false) белиберда;` в обычном коде. Вас удивляет, что код не транслируется? Ну таковы правила языка. Нетранслирующиеся ветки if появились в С++17 - это `if constexpr`

Comment: Так как на этапе трансляции уже известно, что flag=false, то транслятор может вообще не генерировать ни проверку if (flag == true), ни весь код, который под этой веткой вызывается.

Comment: Этим будет заниматься **оптимизатор**. А чтобы объявить компилятору, что можно в принципе игнорировать  код - есть `if constexpr` - см. мой ответ. В VC++ 2017 вполне работает. P.S. Более того - он так и пишет - *" note: Попробуйте использовать инструкцию "if constexpr""* :)

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Из того, что компилятор "может не генерировать код" совсем никак не вытекает, что компилятор не будет выполнять трансляцию ветки. Требования корректности кода под "выключенной" веткой никак не ослабляются. Хотите выключить трансляцию - используйте `if constexpr` в С++17, но и там полную чушь вы в ветке все равно писать не сможете.

Comment: [но и там полную чушь вы в ветке все равно писать не сможете] Это полная чушь только для некоторых типов данных, для других типов данных это будет правильный код. Идея была в том, чтобы константным параметром шаблона подавить генерацию ветки и ошибочную диагностику.

Comment: Без `if constexpr` этого можно было бы добиться, сделав блоки `if` / `else` в виде специализаций шаблонной функции для `true` / `false`.

Comment: [ сделав блоки if / else в виде специализаций шаблонной функции для true / false] смысла нет, тогда проще переписать код ручками для разных типов и не загонять их в один шаблон.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может, попробовать так?

```
template<class Tdata, bool flag> class example{
    Tdata data;
public:
    example(){}
    void run() {
        if constexpr (flag == true) { delete[] data; }
    }
};
```

Так вы полностью исключите из компиляции `delete` при `flag`, равном `true`.

Comment: На попытку использования constexpr транслятор весело пишет [Ошибка C4984 "if constexpr" — расширение языка C++17]

Comment: А вы ему разрешили работать с С++17? Например, ключиком `/std:c++latest`? Или соответствующими настройками проекта? См. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt490614.aspx

Comment: Похоже что не разрешил. А где там в настройках волшебные слова? Да и почему, собственно, они по дефолту отключены?

Comment: Почему отключены - это к Майкрософтам :) Я работаю в командной строке, а в свойствах проекта... Сейчас попробую поискать.

Comment: Проект - Свойства - Свойства конфигурации - С/С++ - Язык - Стандарт языка С++

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Они отключены, так как 1) поддержка С++17 еще далеко не полноценная, 2) этот стандарт нарушает обратную совместимость по многим вопросам (спецификаторы исключений например)

Comment: @VTT Да там, по большому счету, и С++14 не совсем полноценная :)

Comment: @Harry По большему счету, [она почти полноценная](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance#note_G).

Comment: constexpr помогло. Не знаю как там с генерацией кода но во всяком случае диагностика пропала.